# Java alternative to switching on object type

Tags: java

I want to use the command pattern in Java 8 to pass a variety of commands to objects of a variety of classes. The catch is that the objects have members for which I don't want to expose public setters; I want those members to be manipulated *only* through commands. My problem is how to expose those members (or, better, package-private setters) to the command. If I make them part of an interface then I make them public. Inheriting them isn't an option because I'd need multiple inheritance. So how can the command know the setters are available if they're neither exposed as part of the class or as part of an interface?

The best solution I've thought of is to get the relevant classes to switch on the type of command and implement the execution of the command *entirely* within the class (so the members can be private - even better), just pulling the necessary information out of the command class. But the idea of switching on an object type in an OO language makes me feel tainted. Is there a better way?

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just describing the problem.

Comment: A minimal, complete and verifiable example is all very well when one has a design one can't get to work. It's less practical when one doesn't even have a design! So thanks to dasblinkenlight, below, for spotting the pattern I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*Visitor Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

- Your configurable class is the `Visitor`,
- Your command class is the `Element`,
- You pass your configurable class to command's `accept` method, and the command calls a method that corresponds to command's type.

Here is an example:

```
interface CommandVisitor {
    void visit(SetCommand1 cmd);
    void visit(SetCommand2 cmd);
}
interface Command {
    void accept(CommandVisitor v);
}
class SetCommand1 : Command {
    public void accept(CommandVisitor v) {v.visit(this);}
}
class SetCommand2 : Command {
    public void accept(CommandVisitor v) {v.visit(this);}
}
```

Now your configurable class can implement `visit` overloads for `SetCommand1` and `SetCommand2`, which will receive "callbacks" based on the type of the command passed to you.

Comment: This solution requires the 'variety of supported classes', as OP called it, to reside in the same package - in order to have access to the package-private API. But I guess, that comes with your way of solving the [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). Invariant to new commands and variant to new data types.

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes have access to the private members of their enclosing class, so you could make the command a nested class:

```
interface Command {
    void execute();
}

class Model {
    private int fieldA;
    private String fieldB;

    ...

    public Command getCommand() {
        return new MyCommand();
    }

    ...

    private class MyCommand implements Command {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            fieldA = 10;
            fieldB = "Foo";
            //Or use setter...
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Model model = ...;
Command command = model.getCommand();
//usage...
```

This way `MyCommand` can access `Model`'s fields but nothing else can.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution you force the objects to provide the commands themselves. This allows to hide the objects' interna. The commands are all derived from `Command`.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Command { public void execute(); }
```

For example `CommandA`.

```
public interface CommandA extends Command { }
```

The objects that should work with this framework should implement `Commandable`. This interface has a method for every supported command and allows the objects to return their own specific implementation of given command.

```
public interface Commandable { public CommandA getCommandA(); }
```

Use it in following manner.

```
public class Type implements Commandable {

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public CommandA getCommandA() {
        return () -> {isRunning = true;};
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Type type = new Type();
        System.out.println(type.isRunning());

        Commandable object = type;
        CommandA command = object.getCommandA();
        command.execute();

        System.out.println(type.isRunning());
    }

}
```

The output is

```
false
true
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want the objects to implement `Commandable`, you could create some kind of command registry and force every object to register the implementation of the commands (it supports) there.